# how to test text value (regexp) in a nodelist (div)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, casperjs

I need to run a test to check if all my div from a given class are containing a number.

the line I am writing in casper is :

```
'document.querySelectorAll(".line-1 .nb-follower")'.should.have.text(/[0-9]+/);
```

the console is returning the following error :

```
expected 'document.querySelectorAll(".line-1 .af-nb-follower")' to contain /[0-9]+/, but it was ""
```

I try to select item[0]
but I get the same error..

I checked the selector in my console, and I can see my nodeList.
Any ideas would be welcome !!
Best,
André

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to iterate, for instance

```
var elements   = document.querySelectorAll(".line-1 .nb-follower");

var elemArray  = [].slice.call(elements);

var allNumbers = elemArray.every(function(elem) {
    return /[0-9]+/.test.elem.textContent;
});
```

would test each elements text, and return true if every element contained a number between 0 and 9

In ES6

```
var elements   = document.querySelectorAll(".line-1 .nb-follower");
var allNumbers = [...elements].every( elem => /[0-9]+/.test.elem.textContent );
```

Comment: Amazing!
There was just an eror with the var name array, that should be elemArray, but it work great!

Comment: @AndréDjoDjo - oops, fixed the array name now.

Comment: @AndréDjoDjo - you're welcome, remember to accept the answer.